# Passing in optional JSON Post argument to Flask-RestFul?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I would like to modify an existing endpoint to accept an optional POST argument. This has to be optional so that existing iOS clients that call this endpoint with the old version continue to work.

```
class UnlockTempPass(Resource, MixinResource):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UnlockTempPass, self).__init__()
        self.req_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.req_parser.add_argument('token', location='headers')
        # Added this line below
        self.req_parser.add_argument('credit', type=int, required=False)

    def post(self):
        args = self.req_parser.parse_args()
```

However, this crashes right at the line above with the following message:

> 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1
>   column 1 (char 0)

I haven't come across anything that could fix this. Is my only chance to create a whole new endpoint so that existing users aren't disrupted or is there a way to save this? Thanks